# Let $Y ∼ N(−8, 4)$. Compute each of the following, in terms of the function use Table D.2 (or software) to evaluate these probabilities numerically

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $Y ∼ N(−8, 4)$. Compute each of the following, in terms of the function
use Table D.2 (or software) to evaluate these probabilities
numerically

---

(a) $P(Y ≤ −5)$

attempt:

this is $\frac{Y+8}{4} ∼ N(0,1)$ once normalized

$P(Y \leq -5) = \phi(\frac{-5+8}{4}) = \phi(0.75) = 0.7734$

The solution gets $0.933$

Is the soluton wrong?

Comment: Your method is correct, the answer key is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differing notations for the distribution seem to be in play.

Their answer is for $\mathcal N(\mu{:=}{-8}, \sigma^2{:=}4)$.   You have used $\mathcal N(\mu{:=}{-8}, \sigma{:=}4)$.

$$\phi\left(\tfrac{-5+8}{2}\right)\approx 0.933$$

Comment: Different textbooks/authors/lecturers use different notations, and use of $\mathcal N(\mu, \sigma)$ verses $\mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ is a common disagreement. There *should* be specifications included at the start of the topic, or in the codex. Lecturers and question setters *should* follow consistant curriculum standards. However since that isn't always so, in an exam, *you* should state your understanding of the symbols too.